# How to modify View-pager on Real time basis

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-viewpager

I, am new to android. and I created one view pager which fetching image from firebase. and It's working fine. but there are some loopholes in that view pager which I failed to solve.

1) My View-pager not getting update on real-time basis. Means when ever I modify image in firebase. it's does't effect on real-time basis. I have to close my app and then have to start it again for seeing those updates.

2) When I am removing item from my list in firebase. My app getting crashed and in Logcat this exception is thrown.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: -1, Size: 5
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:483)
    at com.release.pack.lootbox.Fragments.HomeFragment$7.onEvent(HomeFragment.java:294)
    at com.release.pack.lootbox.Fragments.HomeFragment$7.onEvent(HomeFragment.java:281)
```

Here is my code:

Slider Image Adapter:

```
public class SliderImageAdapter extends SliderViewAdapter<SliderImageAdapter.SliderAdapterVH> {

    public List<Banner> bannerList;
    public Context context;

    public SliderImageAdapter(Context context, List<Banner> bannerList) {

        this.bannerList = bannerList;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public SliderAdapterVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        View inflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_slider_myshop, parent, false);
        return new SliderAdapterVH(inflate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SliderAdapterVH viewHolder, final int position) {


        Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
                .load(bannerList.get(position).getmSliderImage())
                .fitCenter()
                .into(viewHolder.imageViewBackground);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bannerList.size();
    }


    class SliderAdapterVH extends SliderViewAdapter.ViewHolder {

        View itemView;
        ImageView imageViewBackground;
        ImageView imageGifContainer;
        TextView textViewDescription;
        public ProgressBar progressBar;
        public ImageView imageViewFailed;

        public SliderAdapterVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageViewBackground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_auto_image_slider);
            imageGifContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_gif_container);
            textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_auto_image_slider);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.featured_deal_progress);
            imageViewFailed = itemView.findViewById(R.id.featured_deal_img_failed_to_load);

            this.itemView = itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

Home Fragment :

```
private SliderImageAdapter sliderImageAdapter;
    private List<Banner> bannerList;

bannerList = new ArrayList<>();
        sliderImageAdapter = new SliderImageAdapter(getActivity(),bannerList);

sliderMyshop = view.findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);
        sliderMyshop.setSliderAdapter(sliderImageAdapter);
        sliderMyshop.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimations.WORM); //set indicator animation by using SliderLayout.IndicatorAnimations. :WORM or THIN_WORM or COLOR or DROP or FILL or NONE or SCALE or SCALE_DOWN or SLIDE and SWAP!!
        sliderMyshop.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.SIMPLETRANSFORMATION);
        sliderMyshop.setIndicatorSelectedColor(Color.WHITE);
        sliderMyshop.setIndicatorUnselectedColor(Color.GRAY);
        sliderMyshop.startAutoCycle();



    mFirestore.collection("Banner").orderBy("priority", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error : " + e.getMessage());
                }
                assert documentSnapshots != null;

                for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                        String doc_id = doc.getDocument().getId();
                        Banner banner = doc.getDocument().toObject(Banner.class).withDocId(doc_id);
                        bannerList.add(doc.getNewIndex(), banner);
                        sliderImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } else if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED) {
                        String docID = doc.getDocument().getId();
                        Banner changedModel = doc.getDocument().toObject(Banner.class).withDocId(docID);
                        if (doc.getOldIndex() == doc.getNewIndex()) {
                            // Item changed but remained in same position
                            bannerList.set(doc.getOldIndex(), changedModel);
//                            sliderImageAdapter.notifyItemChanged(doc.getOldIndex());
                        } else {
                            // Item changed and changed position
                            bannerList.remove(doc.getOldIndex());
                            bannerList.add(doc.getNewIndex(), changedModel);
//                            sliderImageAdapter.notifyItemMoved(doc.getOldIndex(), doc.getNewIndex());
                        }
                    } else if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED) {
                        // remove
                        bannerList.remove(doc.getOldIndex());
//                        sliderImageAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(doc.getOldIndex());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

When I am adding a new image in firebase it's getting update on real-time basis. but not when I am doing modification in my image. or removing the item from my list.

Answer (score 0):

> Getting crashed

```
bannerList.add(doc.getNewIndex(), banner);
```

This line is the reason for the **IndexOutOfBoundsException**.

```
(java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: -1, Size: 5)
```

`doc.getNewIndex()` is returning **-1**. and list can not accept -1 as an index. so please check your `doc.getNewIndex()`.

> For realtime update

```
bannerList.clear();
```

add this code before your **for** loop, otherwise redundant data will be added and you can not update the new changes.

See [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen): The snapshot handler will receive a new query snapshot every time the query results change (that is, when a document is added, removed, or modified).

> for every changes whole collection will be fetched

Comment: By using bannerList.clear(); updates are taking place at real-time basis. but instead of update at that particular item. they create new updated item. and when I close the app and start it again after that only i able to see update within that particular item in the list.

Comment: I also write some new code for added, modification and remove. but in that notifyItemChanged(), notifyItemModified(), and notifyItemRemoved() method could not find. I updated my question with my new code

Comment: there is only `notifyItemChanged()` method in the adapter,

and it will update the view with the arraylist elements, You need to control what arraylist elements contains.

If you perform remove, then remove that element from your arraylist then call `notifyItemChanged()` method, If you perform edit, then edit that element from your arraylist then call `notifyItemChanged()` method same for other cases update delete